# jQuery - How to slide the bottom part up after the top part is fadeout?

Tags: jquery

I have a page as follows:

```
<div id="warning_msg">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Praesent aliquam, justo.
<span id="closeerrordiv" class="notify-close">×</span>
</div>
<div id="bigForm2">
    Lots of content here    
</div>
<div id="bigForm...">
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#closeerrordiv').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
    });
});    
</script>
```

After the user clicks 'closeerrordiv', the span content will fadeout.
Now, I need to move all the bottom parts move up.

Howe can I do this?

Comment: The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.
Do you mean you have a blank space instead of your element??

Comment: Hello Sergey,

You are right, the parent DIV will disappear. Then what happens is that the bottom part of the page will jump up to fill the gap left by the disappeared DIV. I want to make this part as an animation so that the bottom part moves up slowly.

If you notice stackoverflow.com, when you login you see 

Welcome to Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers -- check out the FAQ!

Then when you click x, the bottom part slowly moves up!

Than you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'jump' happens because fadeOut() function in the end sets 'display' to 'none'.
This will solve your problem:

```
$(this).parent().animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
  // fade complete.
  $('#warning_msg').slideUp('slow');
});
```

If you want simultaneous fading and sliding just write:

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut('slow').slideUp('slow');
```

Comment: You can chain stuff in Jquery.  $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow').slideUp('slow'); works too.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the callback function to `fadeOut` like this to slide up the element after fading completes:

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function(){
  $('#element_id').slideUp('slow');
});
```

Where `element_id` is the `id` of the element you want to move/slide up.

Comment: Hello Sarfraz,

I don't have one solid element_id that contains all the bottom parts.

Comment: Author means 'a jump' after fading. This will not solve his problem.

Comment: @q0987: So which element you want to slide up then, which parts of html in your question, you have not mentioned this. We can not understand what you mean by bottom parts.

Comment: He ment that after fading of the 'top' the 'bottom' should slide but not jump => so the 'top' should slide actually just after fading

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what you mean by what you said.

it sounds like you want the 'x' to fade out and then slide out the warning message. to do that do the following javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#closeerrordiv').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $(this).parent().slideUp();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello jairajs89,

When the click happens, the parent of span #closeerrordiv (i.e., warning_msg) disappear.

Here is what I want to do:

I would like to use animation so that the DIV #bigForm2, ..., #footer are sliding up.

what happens now is that all the DIV are jumping to above.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Add [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) right after the `fadeOut()`.

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
$(this).parent().slideUp('slow');
```

Comment: this will do them both at the same time.

Comment: Will it? I was going on the code samples at http://api.jquery.com/queue/. Maybe I just interpreted it wrong?